# Is the collection of all bijective string maps a set or a class?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, formal-languages

Let $\Sigma$ be a finite alphabet and $B = \{ f: \Sigma^* \to \Sigma^* \text{ bijectively} \}$, where a string map is not always a homomorphism.  I am always having trouble deciding whether something is a set or a class.  Need to study more category theory!

Comment: $\Sigma^*$ is a set, $\Sigma^* \times \Sigma^*$ is a set, and ...

Answer (score 3):

This isn't really a question about category theory; rather, it's about set theory. The following is the key fact you want:

> If $A, B$ are sets, then the class of functions from $A$ to $B$ is a set.

(Note that one application of this is that $\Sigma^*$ is a set if $\Sigma$ is.)

Why is this true?

- First, show that $A\times B$ is a set.
- Now any map $f: A\rightarrow B$ is a subset of $A\times B$ (in set theory, we identify a function with its graph)
- So the *class* of all bijective maps $A\rightarrow B$ is contained in the powerset of $A\times B$ which is a set . . . by the Powerset axiom.
- Do you see how to show, therefore, that the class of all bijective maps $A\rightarrow B$ is a set? (HINT: Separation . . .)

You will probably get a lot out of [reading through the axioms of ZFC in detail](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zermelo%E2%80%93Fraenkel_set_theory). Note that there are some variations: e.g. Separation/Subset/Specification, Replacement/Collection, Foundation/Regularity, and the axiom of Emptyset (which isn't necessary due to the behavior of first-order logic, but which *is* necessary if you want to consider empty structures and you want to ditch the axiom of Infinity).

Comment: This is a standard technique in set theory: to show that something is a set, you basically overshoot wildly with Powerset (possibly plus Replacement), and then use Separation to cut things down to what you actually want. There *are* often more graceful ways to do this . . . but come on, nobody advocates ZFC because of how gracefully it proves theorems. :P